# Event listener in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create a function that accepts the parameter as a function?

I have this function and I want to call it with parameter of a function also:

```
function ShowDialog(OnSubmit) 
{
    var _result = OnSubmit();

    alert(_result);
}
```

This is what I want to call:

```
ShowDialog(
              {
                  OnSubmit: function () {
                      return "Hello World";
                  }
              }
          );

this will alert "Hello World in browser"
```

Comment: You're passing an object with a property but expecting a function…

Comment: What is the requirement behind this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), so you can just pass the function reference directly, you do not need an object:

```
function showDialog(callback) {
    var result = callback();
    alert(result);
}

function bye() { return "bye!" };

showDialog(function() { return "Hello!" });
showDialog(bye);

var greetings = { ciao: function() { return "Ciao!" } };

showDialog(greetings.ciao);
```

Of course you can also pass the full object, in that case you need to modify the function as follow:

```
function showDialog(options) {
    var result = options.onSubmit();
    alert(result);
}
```

And then:

```
showDialog({
    onSubmit: function() { return "Hello!" }
});

showDialog({
    onSubmit: bye
});
```

You could also implement a function that accepts both object and callback:

```
function showDialog(options) {
    var result = typeof options === 'function' ? options() : options.onSubmit();
    alert(result);
}

showDialog({
    onSubmit: bye
});

showDialog(bye);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Call:

```
ShowDialog(function(){
   return "Hello World";
});
```

Then your function can remain as:

```
function ShowDialog(OnSubmit) 
{
    var _result = OnSubmit();

    alert(_result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
function ShowDialog(param) 
{
    var _result = param.OnSubmit();
    alert(_result);
}

ShowDialog({
    OnSubmit: function () {
         return "Hello World";
    }
});
```